# "Bob's and my effort" or "Bob's and my efforts"?

Tags: word-usage

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/effort) gives this definition of "effort"

> physical or mental activity needed to achieve something

with that meaning, "effort" could be **[ C or U ]**, how do I distinguish the use?

for example,

> after **Bob's and my effort**, the project has been delivered successfully.
>
> after **Bob's and my efforts**, the project has been delivered successfully.

which one should I use, and why?

Comment: Personally I would say, "After the efforts of Bob and myself, ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several use cases here:

1. Bob and I, as a team, made, an effort.
2. Bob and I, individually, each made an effort.
3. Bob and I, as a team, made efforts.
4. Bob and I, individually, made efforts.

This phrase:

> after **Bob's and my effort**,...

seems to see all the effort (could be several actions) that went into it as one object, so seems to correspond most closely to case 1, but not the others. Case 2 is marginal at best, I think. Consider:

> Bob put in effort on Monday. I did on Tuesday. After **Bob's and my effort**, the project was delivered.

This would be clearer with "efforts" or better rendered as:

> after **bob's effort and my effort**,...
>   or equivalently,
>
> after **bob's efforts and my efforts**,...

because effort and efforts effectively mean the same thing, but it is a question of how the speaker views it. That's why case 1 could also be rendered as:

> after **Bob's and my efforts**,...

If the speaker really wants to make the Count distinction:

> after **bob's effort and my efforts**,...
>
> after **bob's efforts and my effort**,...

Awkward, but precise and grammatically correct.

Case 3 and 4 imply that the efforts are being viewed as individual items.

> after **Bob's and my efforts**, the project has been delivered successfully.

I think this is where the ambiguity is. I find it hard to distinguish cases 2, 3 and 4 with this example. Context is all that is left.

End result is effort works with case 1, efforts works with case 1, 3, and 4. 2 should be rendered differently.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. In real life use, the speaker typically wants to convey the idea that both of them have made contribution to that project and doesn't want to distinguish their efforts, that is the case 1, right?

Comment: I would say that either 1 or 3 represents that case. If you want to convey that the efforts were many, use the C version. If you want to convey that the effort was one grand action, use the NC/U version. It is a matter of nuance (or context). Either phrase works for your idea, but case 3 is not covered by effort. case 1 is covered by both. Safest route: efforts, but it doesn't exclude 4, but as you said, that is unusual and probably not detrimental, because even if you make no distinction, the distinction exists (as they are different people). Sorry, wordy reply, but if you follow it....